# Story link flow using SSO facebook - openURL not being called

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, fbconnect, openurl

I have implemented Single-Sign-On in my iOS 4.3 app successfully. Now I want to publish a link to the users facebook wall so that when his/her friends that also own the app clicks the link they should be redirected to my app. The way I interpret http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#deeplink , is that one of the delegate functions

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url, (pre iOS 4.2)
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
 sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation , (iOS 4.2+)
```

will be called and that the shared link can be parsed from the [target_link] key. However, I can't get this to work. I successfully post my link to the users news feed using:

```
   NSDictionary* params=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:myFacebookAppID,@"app_id",
 linkToPost,@"link",nil];
 [_facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self]
```

The post appear on my news feed but when i click the link none of the delegate methods mentioned above is being called. Should I do something special with the link, I have tried adding "fb:myFacebookAppID://" in front of the link but that doesn't work at all. Have I misunderstood something?

My app is not yet live on AppStore and there is a field on developers.facebook.com where I am asked to enter my AppStore ID, could this be the problem? If so, is there any workaround? I want to test that this works as it should before sending my app to AppStore.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have your facebook instace in AppDelegate for example:

```
@interface FacebookAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController; 
@property (nonatomic, strong) Facebook *facebook;

@end

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary     *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[FacebookViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FacebookViewController" bundle:nil];

    self.facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId andDelegate:(id)self.viewController];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
        self.facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        self.facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

And inside AppDelegate you have to implement:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [self.facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [self.facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

And if you want to implement protocol in your own class you have to call facebook on this:

```
FacebookAppDelegate *fbAppDelegate = (FacebookAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"publish_stream",@"create_event",@"offline_access", nil];

[[fbAppDelegate facebook] authorize:permissions];
```