# iPhone: Issue when posting message using Facebook wall APIs

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

I have been following through the below link for Facebook integration and could able to successfully post message on the wall without any issues. I registered an App ID for my iPhone app.

http://gabriel-tips.blogspot.in/2011/10/how-to-post-on-facebook-wall-through.html

But, after a month (not exactly a month, it may be more than 1 month), problem posting the message on the wall with the same application, i.e. App shows "Your message has been posted on your wall!" when executing the code `-(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result` in this function.
But, it actually have not posted on the wall.

What may be the issue here? Does FB App ID works only for certain time period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can I suggest this official Facebook API instructions for integration for iOS:

[iOS Tutorial - Facebook API (press here!)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/)

add some more of your code, also a suggestion:
Put your INITILIAZTION of the Facebook class IN the App Delegate and reference your Facebook class using the App Delegate singleton inside another file

Comment: Hi, Thanks, but the same thing is there, and the same issue has observed.

Comment: ok, that is missing in my code, i have not put in Appdelegate, is it must?

Comment: well maybe... you see my Facebook was never actually working/unsuccesfully logging in, then I asked a question on this website and someone answered with that. Check out my question. It worked!

Comment: Its the newest Facebook question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9858894/facebook-sso-not-logging-in-issessionvalid-returns-no-all-the-time